# how to avoid duplicate values in sql LIke query

Tags: php, yii

I implement my project in Yii. To display search values using sql LIKE query. and its also displaying. but i fetching values from other table using primary key. so that i assigned values to id only. and its also displaying correct. but there is duplicate values displaying ie. my table containing from id 1 to 23. if i select the first values. values are displaying like
1,10,11,12,13,21 like wise then if i select 2 values are displaying like 2,20,21,22 like wise values are displaying.

i added my query here please suggest my suitable answer accordingly.

```
 $result="SELECT * FROM recipe WHERE name LIKE '%$name%' AND `cuisinename` LIKE '$cuisine1%' AND course_id  LIKE '%$course1%' AND `type` LIKE '%$type1%' AND `calorie_count` LIKE '%$calorie1%' ORDER BY recipe_id DESC LIMIT 15";
```

above cuisiname need to display  properly

Comment: What is the exact problem?

Comment: Try using groupby name at end of query

Comment: i using dropdown values dynamically. if i select dropdown value 1 mean. i getting to display 1,11,21 like displaying. ie 1 contain italian, 21 is india, 11 is french so these are displaying to my content

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM recipe ...
```